# IntelliJ Reformat Settings

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

For my Flutter project, I have my dependencies setup as such:

```
// Dependencies
// ------------

// Packages
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
// Widgets
import '../widgets/ring-swipe.dart';
```

However, when I use `Reformat Code` in IntelliJ, my comments turn into:

```
// Dependencies
// ------------

// Packages
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/ring-swipe.dart';
```

I can't seem to find where this setting is set for Dart/Flutter projects. Is this non-configurable?

Comment: The widgets comment is removed?

Comment: @LppEdd Correct

Answer (score 1):

This behavior seems related to issue [IDEA-171179](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171179) (and duplicates), which is still open, unfortunately.
See, specifically, this Dart example, which seems to match.

Before reformat code:

```
// ignore: unused_import
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout_classes.dart';

// ignore: unused_import
import 'package:polymer_elements/app_layout/app_header/app_header.dart';
```

After reformat code:

```
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout_classes.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/app_layout/app_header/app_header.dart';

// ignore: unused_import
// ignore: unused_import
```

Valid for the old IDEA `2017.1`

---

To mitigate the issue, remove the *Optimize imports* check.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this still moves comments around, but does work a little better

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren can't do anything better I'm afraid. You can post on YouTrack about your issue.

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren Were you able to find anything better?

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm afraid

Comment: @JoshuaVanDeren Maybe if there are other votes for the issue they'll fix it sooner